# JQuery Ajax DataTables retain leading zeros

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Our web app is built in Perl, and utilizes MySQL tables using the Ajax DataTables library/package. https://datatables.net/

While there is a layer of complexity due to building the raw data in scripting in Perl, it has served us well, however there seems to be a single column value randomly being interpreted as a number, and getting its leading zeros dropped.

The MySQL column value is a proper varchar, and Perl is displaying that varchar value elsewhere fine. It seems to be happening when passed to the Datatable constructor in JQuery.

I've been reading the DataTables docs, but their examples really don't translate to this situation very well.

```
# Perls raw jquery config getting passed
#
my $config = <<'EOD';
    {
      buttons: [],
      lengthMenu: [ [25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
      columnDefs: [{
        targets: "6", data: "string" 
      }],
    }
EOD
```

I believe the secret lies in ColumnDefs, but the DataTables documentation is a bit confusing to me. My passed config is doing nothing. It doesn't error, but it also just doesn't do anything.

So column number 6 is our `member_id` varchar column, and say if a member id is `0012345`, it will only displaying `12345`.

I was doing a hardcore deep dive into this issue, and the DataTables forum had something sort of similar here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/65305/leading-zero-problem

However, the solution they used was in PHP, and they also seemed to be using a POST method?

If anyone has good familiarity with this package, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this in your DataTables initialization:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    buttons: [],
    lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: 1, // Index of the Member ID column
        render: function(data, type, row) {
          return type === 'display' ? data : String(data);
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Member ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>0012345</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The render function here checks if the rendering type is 'display'; if it is, it returns the data as is, but if not, it explicitly converts the data to a string. This should ensure that DataTables treats the data in column 6 as a string and retains the leading zeros.

Comment: From one programmer to another, thank you so much for clearing up the proper syntax for that. I hope this solution helps other folks too.